# How to pass output variables of CodePipeline Lambda Action to CodeBuild action

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I'm trying to build a simple CICD Pipeline usind CDK python library. I have the code for creating a construct which consists of the following:

1. A Lambda Function to be used inside a codepipeline action. Main purpose of this lambda function is to get the output values for a cloudformation stack that is in another account.
2. CodeBuild project.
3. CodePipeline Project:

   - Source
   - Lambda Invoke Action (uses previously created lambda function)
   - Build stage

I want to pass on some output values from the lambda invoke action to the build stage. However, after defining the environment variables when creating the codebuild project construct, they are not being passed at all.

This is the code I have for the cdk application:

```py
class ModelDeployCICDStack(Stack):
    
    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, envs_deployment,**kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)
        
        codebuild_lambda_role = iam.Role(
            self,
            "CodeBuildLambdaInvokeAction",
            role_name=f"CICDPipelineCodeBuildLambdaInvokeRole",
            managed_policies=[
                iam.ManagedPolicy.from_aws_managed_policy_name("AWSLambda_FullAccess"),
                iam.ManagedPolicy.from_aws_managed_policy_name("CloudWatchFullAccess")
            ],
            assumed_by=iam.CompositePrincipal(
                iam.ServicePrincipal("lambda.amazonaws.com"),
            )
        )
        
        codebuild_lambda_role.add_to_policy(
            iam.PolicyStatement(
                    actions=["sts:AssumeRole"],
                    resources=["arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXX:role/DescribeCfnStackRole"]
                )
        )
        
        my_lambda = _lambda.Function(
            self,
            "CfnCAALambdaFunc",
            runtime=_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_8,
            code=_lambda.Code.from_asset("ticket_irregularities_cicd_cdk/lambda"),
            handler="cfn_caa_helper.lambda_handler",
            role = codebuild_lambda_role
            
        )
        
        lambda_invoke_action = aws_codepipeline_actions.LambdaInvokeAction(
            action_name="Lambda",
            lambda_= my_lambda,
            variables_namespace="ConfigMetadata"
        )
        
        # Create CodePipeline project
        # Note: It is created here so resource s3 bucket can be referenced 
        pipeline = codepipeline.Pipeline(
            self, "CodePipeline",
            pipeline_name="ModelDeploy-CodePipeline",
        )
        
        # Create codebuild role
        codebuild_role = iam.Role(
            self, 
            "CodeBuildRole",
            role_name = f"CodeBuildRoleModelDeployPipeline",
            assumed_by = iam.CompositePrincipal(iam.ServicePrincipal("codebuild.amazonaws.com"), 
                                                iam.ServicePrincipal("codepipeline.amazonaws.com")
            )
        )
        
        # Define the CodeBuild project for the building of the model deployment code
        # For this, the output of running the code, is a set of Cloudformation templates
        build_project_execute = codebuild.PipelineProject(
            self, id = "CodeBuildProject",
            project_name="ModelDeploy-CodeBuild",
            role=codebuild_role,
            build_spec = codebuild.BuildSpec.from_source_filename("buildspec.yml"),
            environment= codebuild.BuildEnvironment(build_image=codebuild.LinuxBuildImage.AMAZON_LINUX_2_2,),
            environment_variables={
                "SAGEMAKER_EXECUTION_ROLE_ARN_DEV": codebuild.BuildEnvironmentVariable(
                    type=codebuild.BuildEnvironmentVariableType.PLAINTEXT,
                    value= envs_deployment["dev"]["sagemaker"]
                ),
                "LAMBDA_EXECUTION_ROLE_ARN_DEV": codebuild.BuildEnvironmentVariable(
                    type=codebuild.BuildEnvironmentVariableType.PLAINTEXT,
                    value= envs_deployment["dev"]["lambda"]
                ),
                "DEFAULT_BUCKET_DEV": codebuild.BuildEnvironmentVariable(
                    type=codebuild.BuildEnvironmentVariableType.PLAINTEXT,
                    value= envs_deployment["dev"]["pipeline_bucket"]
                ),
                "SAGEMAKER_EXECUTION_ROLE_ARN_STAGING": codebuild.BuildEnvironmentVariable(
                    type=codebuild.BuildEnvironmentVariableType.PLAINTEXT,
                    value= "#{ConfigMetadata.SMRoleArn}"
                ),
                "LAMBDA_EXECUTION_ROLE_ARN_STAGING": codebuild.BuildEnvironmentVariable(
                    type=codebuild.BuildEnvironmentVariableType.PLAINTEXT,
                    value= "#{ConfigMetadata.LambdaRoleArn}"
                ),
                "DEFAULT_BUCKET_STAGING": codebuild.BuildEnvironmentVariable(
                    type=codebuild.BuildEnvironmentVariableType.PLAINTEXT,
                    value= "#{ConfigMetadata.S3BucketName}"
                ),
                "ARTIFACT_BUCKET": codebuild.BuildEnvironmentVariable(
                    type=codebuild.BuildEnvironmentVariableType.PLAINTEXT,
                    value= pipeline.artifact_bucket.bucket_name
                ),
                "MODEL_BUILD_S3_BUCKET": codebuild.BuildEnvironmentVariable(
                    type=codebuild.BuildEnvironmentVariableType.PLAINTEXT,
                    value=envs_deployment["dev"]["modelbuild_bucket"]
                ),
                "EXPORT_TEMPLATE_NAME": codebuild.BuildEnvironmentVariable(
                    type=codebuild.BuildEnvironmentVariableType.PLAINTEXT,
                    value= "template-export.yml"
                ),
                "EXPORT_TEMPLATE_DEV_CONFIG": codebuild.BuildEnvironmentVariable(
                    type=codebuild.BuildEnvironmentVariableType.PLAINTEXT,
                    value= "dev-config-export.json"
                ),
                "EXPORT_TEMPLATE_STAGING_CONFIG": codebuild.BuildEnvironmentVariable(
                    type=codebuild.BuildEnvironmentVariableType.PLAINTEXT,
                    value= "staging-config-export.json"
                ),
                "EXPORT_TEMPLATE_PROD_CONFIG": codebuild.BuildEnvironmentVariable(
                    type=codebuild.BuildEnvironmentVariableType.PLAINTEXT,
                    value= "prod-config-export.json"
                ),
            }
        )
        
        # Define source action - what repository to look for changes
        # Note: The connection needs to be set up manually once - using the console
        source_code_output= codepipeline.Artifact()
        
        source_action = aws_codepipeline_actions.CodeStarConnectionsSourceAction(
            action_name="Github_Source_ModelDeploy",
            owner="XXXXXXXXXX",
            repo="sm-modeldeploy",
            branch="main",
            output=source_code_output,
            connection_arn="arn:aws:codestar-connections:eu-north-1:XXXXXXXXXX:connection/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        )
        
        # Define approval action before executing codebuild project
        manual_approval_for_build = aws_codepipeline_actions.ManualApprovalAction(
            action_name="ApproveBuildingTemplates",
        )
           
        source_input_cfn_template = codepipeline.Artifact("artifact1")
        source_input_cfn_template_1 = codepipeline.Artifact("artifact2")
        source_input_cfn_template_2 = codepipeline.Artifact("artifact3")
        source_input_cfn_template_3 = codepipeline.Artifact("artifact4")
        
        # Define code build action (which will used previous codebuild project and code source output)
        # The underlying codebuild project, produces some output/artifacts files that will be used later on
        build_action = aws_codepipeline_actions.CodeBuildAction(
            action_name="BuildCfnTemplatesDeployment",
            project=build_project_execute,
            input=source_code_output,
            outputs=[source_input_cfn_template, source_input_cfn_template_1, source_input_cfn_template_2, source_input_cfn_template_3]
        )
   
        
        # Add stage with source action
        pipeline.add_stage(stage_name="Source", actions=[source_action])
        
        # Add lambda invoke action
        pipeline.add_stage(stage_name="LambdaInvoke", actions=[lambda_invoke_action])
        
        # Add stage with manual approval action
        pipeline.add_stage(stage_name="Approve", actions=[manual_approval_for_build])
        
        # Add stage with build action
        pipeline.add_stage(stage_name="Build", actions=[build_action])
```

And this is the code for the lambda function that is used for the CodePipeline action:

```py
import boto3
import json

CODEPIPELINE_CLIENT = boto3.client('codepipeline')

def assume_crossaccount_role(role_arn, role_session_name="cfn_lookup_outputs"):

    role_info = {
        'RoleArn': role_arn,
        'RoleSessionName': role_session_name
    }

    client = boto3.client('sts')
    credentials = client.assume_role(**role_info)

    session = boto3.session.Session(
        aws_access_key_id=credentials['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'],
        aws_secret_access_key=credentials['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey'],
        aws_session_token=credentials['Credentials']['SessionToken']
    )

    return session

boto_session = assume_crossaccount_role("arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:role/DescribeCfnStackRole")
CF_CLIENT = boto_session.client('cloudformation')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    # Replace 'your-stack-name' with the name of your CloudFormation stack
    stack_name = 'ModelDeployStaging-ModelDeployInfra'

    try:
        # Describe the stack to get its information
        response = CF_CLIENT.describe_stacks(StackName=stack_name)

        # Extract the stack outputs
        stack = response['Stacks'][0]  # Assuming there is only one stack with this name
        outputs = stack.get('Outputs', [])

        if not outputs:
            # Report failure to CodePipeline
            CODEPIPELINE_CLIENT.put_job_failure_result(
                jobId=event['CodePipeline.job']['id'],
                failureDetails={
                    'type': 'JobFailed',
                    'message': f"No outputs found for stack '{stack_name}'"
                }
            )
        else:
            output_dict = {output['OutputKey']: output['OutputValue'] for output in outputs}
            print(output_dict)
            # Report success to CodePipeline with the output values
            CODEPIPELINE_CLIENT.put_job_success_result(
                jobId=event['CodePipeline.job']['id'],
                outputVariables=output_dict
            )
    except Exception as e:
        # Report failure to CodePipeline with the error message
        CODEPIPELINE_CLIENT.put_job_failure_result(
            jobId=event['CodePipeline.job']['id'],
            failureDetails={
                'type': 'JobFailed',
                'message': f"Error: {str(e)}"
            }
        )
```

Here: the variable `output_dict`  has the following value `{'SMRoleArn': 'arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXX:role/SageMakerExecXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', 'LambdaRoleArn': 'arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXX:role/LambdaExecutioXXXXXXXXXX', 'S3BucketName': 'modeldeploystaging-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'}` And I'm passing them using the .put_job_success_result method in the lambda function.

In my build stage, within the CodePipeline project, I have a simple buildspec file that has the commands to print out the value of the environment variables, but it doesn't print the correct values.

Am I missing something obvious? Can someone help  me out on this?

I have taken this question and accepted answer as reference: [How to fetch SSM Parameters from two different accounts using AWS CDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61603414/how-to-fetch-ssm-parameters-from-two-different-accounts-using-aws-cdk) But i had no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to what I was doing wrong. I was not grasping the difference between the stages of the CodePipeline, the actions in each stage, and the action provider (for example, codebuild project). The output variables from the Lambda action should be given to the build action environment variables, and these will be propagated to the action provider, in this case, the codebuild project build will have those environment variables.

Here is the code for defining the Stack for the CodePipeline project.

```py
class ModelDeployCICDStack(Stack):
    
    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, envs_deployment,**kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)
        
        codebuild_lambda_role = iam.Role(
            self,
            "CodeBuildLambdaInvokeAction",
            role_name=f"CICDPipelineCodeBuildLambdaInvokeRole",
            managed_policies=[
                iam.ManagedPolicy.from_aws_managed_policy_name("AWSLambda_FullAccess"),
                iam.ManagedPolicy.from_aws_managed_policy_name("CloudWatchFullAccess")
            ],
            assumed_by=iam.CompositePrincipal(
                iam.ServicePrincipal("lambda.amazonaws.com"),
            )
        )
        
        codebuild_lambda_role.add_to_policy(
            iam.PolicyStatement(
                    actions=["sts:AssumeRole"],
                    resources=["arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXX:role/DescribeCfnStackRole"]
                )
        )
        
        my_lambda = _lambda.Function(
            self,
            "CfnCAALambdaFunc",
            runtime=_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_8,
            code=_lambda.Code.from_asset("ticket_irregularities_cicd_cdk/lambda"),
            handler="cfn_caa_helper.lambda_handler",
            role = codebuild_lambda_role
            
        )
        
        lambda_invoke_action = aws_codepipeline_actions.LambdaInvokeAction(
            action_name="Lambda",
            lambda_= my_lambda,
            variables_namespace="ConfigMetadata"
        )
        
        # Create CodePipeline project
        # Note: It is created here so resource s3 bucket can be referenced 
        pipeline = codepipeline.Pipeline(
            self, "CodePipeline",
            pipeline_name="ModelDeploy-CodePipeline",
        )
        
        # Create codebuild role
        codebuild_role = iam.Role(
            self, 
            "CodeBuildRole",
            role_name = f"CodeBuildRoleModelDeployPipeline",
            assumed_by = iam.CompositePrincipal(iam.ServicePrincipal("codebuild.amazonaws.com"), 
                                                iam.ServicePrincipal("codepipeline.amazonaws.com")
            )
        )
        
        # Define the CodeBuild project for the building of the model deployment code
        # For this, the output of running the code, is a set of Cloudformation templates
        build_project_execute = codebuild.PipelineProject(
            self, id = "CodeBuildProject",
            project_name="ModelDeploy-CodeBuild",
            role=codebuild_role,
            build_spec = codebuild.BuildSpec.from_source_filename("buildspec.yml"),
            environment= codebuild.BuildEnvironment(build_image=codebuild.LinuxBuildImage.AMAZON_LINUX_2_2,),
            environment_variables={
                "SAGEMAKER_EXECUTION_ROLE_ARN_DEV": codebuild.BuildEnvironmentVariable(
                    type=codebuild.BuildEnvironmentVariableType.PLAINTEXT,
                    value= envs_deployment["dev"]["sagemaker"]
                ),
                "LAMBDA_EXECUTION_ROLE_ARN_DEV": codebuild.BuildEnvironmentVariable(
                    type=codebuild.BuildEnvironmentVariableType.PLAINTEXT,
                    value= envs_deployment["dev"]["lambda"]
                ),
                "DEFAULT_BUCKET_DEV": codebuild.BuildEnvironmentVariable(
                    type=codebuild.BuildEnvironmentVariableType.PLAINTEXT,
                    value= envs_deployment["dev"]["pipeline_bucket"]
                ),
                "ARTIFACT_BUCKET": codebuild.BuildEnvironmentVariable(
                    type=codebuild.BuildEnvironmentVariableType.PLAINTEXT,
                    value= pipeline.artifact_bucket.bucket_name
                ),
                "MODEL_BUILD_S3_BUCKET": codebuild.BuildEnvironmentVariable(
                    type=codebuild.BuildEnvironmentVariableType.PLAINTEXT,
                    value=envs_deployment["dev"]["modelbuild_bucket"]
                ),
                "EXPORT_TEMPLATE_NAME": codebuild.BuildEnvironmentVariable(
                    type=codebuild.BuildEnvironmentVariableType.PLAINTEXT,
                    value= "template-export.yml"
                ),
                "EXPORT_TEMPLATE_DEV_CONFIG": codebuild.BuildEnvironmentVariable(
                    type=codebuild.BuildEnvironmentVariableType.PLAINTEXT,
                    value= "dev-config-export.json"
                ),
                "EXPORT_TEMPLATE_STAGING_CONFIG": codebuild.BuildEnvironmentVariable(
                    type=codebuild.BuildEnvironmentVariableType.PLAINTEXT,
                    value= "staging-config-export.json"
                ),
                "EXPORT_TEMPLATE_PROD_CONFIG": codebuild.BuildEnvironmentVariable(
                    type=codebuild.BuildEnvironmentVariableType.PLAINTEXT,
                    value= "prod-config-export.json"
                ),
            }
        )
        
        # Define source action - what repository to look for changes
        # Note: The connection needs to be set up manually once - using the console
        source_code_output= codepipeline.Artifact()
        
        source_action = aws_codepipeline_actions.CodeStarConnectionsSourceAction(
            action_name="Github_Source_ModelDeploy",
            owner="XXXXXXXXX",
            repo="sm-modeldeploy",
            branch="main",
            output=source_code_output,
            connection_arn="arn:aws:codestar-connections:eu-north-1:XXXXXXXXXXXXXX:connection/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        )
        
        # Define approval action before executing codebuild project
        manual_approval_for_build = aws_codepipeline_actions.ManualApprovalAction(
            action_name="ApproveBuildingTemplates",
            run_order=1
        )
        
#         # Define approval section before deploying cloudformation template to dev
#         manual_approval_for_cloudformation = aws_codepipeline_actions.ManualApprovalAction(
#             action_name="ApproveDeploymentDev"
#         )
           
        source_input_cfn_template = codepipeline.Artifact("artifact1")
        source_input_cfn_template_1 = codepipeline.Artifact("artifact2")
        source_input_cfn_template_2 = codepipeline.Artifact("artifact3")
        source_input_cfn_template_3 = codepipeline.Artifact("artifact4")
        
        # Define code build action (which will used previous codebuild project and code source output)
        # The underlying codebuild project, produces some output/artifacts files that will be used later on
        build_action = aws_codepipeline_actions.CodeBuildAction(
            action_name="BuildCfnTemplatesDeployment",
            project=build_project_execute,
            input=source_code_output,
            outputs=[source_input_cfn_template, source_input_cfn_template_1, source_input_cfn_template_2, source_input_cfn_template_3],
            environment_variables={
                "SAGEMAKER_EXECUTION_ROLE_ARN_STAGING": codebuild.BuildEnvironmentVariable(
                    type=codebuild.BuildEnvironmentVariableType.PLAINTEXT,
                    value= lambda_invoke_action.variable("SMRoleArn")
                ),
                "LAMBDA_EXECUTION_ROLE_ARN_STAGING": codebuild.BuildEnvironmentVariable(
                    type=codebuild.BuildEnvironmentVariableType.PLAINTEXT,
                    value= lambda_invoke_action.variable("LambdaRoleArn")
                ),
                "DEFAULT_BUCKET_STAGING": codebuild.BuildEnvironmentVariable(
                    type=codebuild.BuildEnvironmentVariableType.PLAINTEXT,
                    value= lambda_invoke_action.variable("S3BucketName")
                ),
            },
            run_order=2
        )
        
#         # Define deploy action in dev account - action creates/updates a cloudformation stack
#         dev_deploy_action = aws_codepipeline_actions.CloudFormationCreateUpdateStackAction(
#             action_name="CloudFormationDeployDev",
#             admin_permissions=True,
#             template_path=source_input_cfn_template.at_path("template-export.yml"),
#             template_configuration=source_input_cfn_template_1.at_path("dev-config-export.json"),
#             stack_name="CICDPipeline-ModelDeploy-Dev"
#         )
        
        # Add stage with source action
        pipeline.add_stage(stage_name="Source", actions=[source_action])
        
        # Add lambda invoke action
        pipeline.add_stage(stage_name="LambdaInvoke", actions=[lambda_invoke_action])
        
        # Add stage with manual approval action
        pipeline.add_stage(
            stage_name="BuilSageMakerPipelineDeploy", 
            actions=[
                manual_approval_for_build, 
                build_action
            ]
        )
```

Hope the code can be useful to others, as an example to how to build a CodePipeline project with a Lambda action, which can be used to perform X operation and pass output variables to following actions.